# При нажатии на чекбокс не срабатывает событие change

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, coffeescript

При нажатии на чекбокс должно сработать событие change. В котором все другие чекбоксы должны стать unckecked. При нажатии ничего не происходит, поставил точку останова, даже не заходит. Что именно ни так? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Использую для отображения чекбоксов библиотеку https://github.com/fntneves/jquery-labelauty

**projects.coffee**

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->

  $('.control__check').labelauty
    checked_label: "Cancel",
    unchecked_label: "Select",
    force_random_id: true


   $('.control__check').change ->
        thisElement = $(this)
        if ($(this).prop("checked"))
          $('ul.content-list content-list__my-response content-list_responses').
            find('.control__check labelauty').each (index, elem) ->
              if ($(elem).prop("checked") && !thisElement )
                elem.prop('checked', false)
```

**_responses.html.erb**

```
<ul class="content-list content-list__my-response content-list_responses">
  <% @project.responses.each do |response| %> 
    <% if response.persisted? %>
      ................................................................        
          <div class="controls">
            <%= check_box_tag '', true, false, { class: "control__check" } %>  
          </div>
      .................................................................    
        </li>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНО 14.06.16:**

Это исходный код чекбокса HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dfvfvfdvf" id="labelauty-179303" value="true"         class="control__check labelauty" style="display: none;">
     <label for="labelauty-179303"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image</span>
  <span class="labelauty-unchecked">Select</span>
  <span class="labelauty-checked-image"></span>
  <span class="labelauty-checked">Cancel</span></label>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если честно, какое-то сильное колдунство для переключения. Я подозреваю, что дело вот в этом:

> $('ul.content-list content-list__my-response content-list_responses')
>
> find('.control__check labelauty')

В обоих случаях селектор неправильный. Нет в HTML тэгов `labelauty`, `content-list_responses` и `content-list__my-response`. Видимо, по задумке, это должны быть классы, а селекторы для классов начинаются с `.`.
Подробности [тут.](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
Если очень хочется повесить событие на изменение оригинальных чекбоксов - можно брать оригинальный селектор: `$('.control__check')`

Но зачем так сложно? Судя по примерам этого плагина, он умеет работать с инпутами типа `radio`. Соответственно, велосипед не нужен:

```
<% @project.responses.each do |response| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag 'my_radio', true, false, { class: "control__check" } %>
<% end %>

$('.control__check').labelauty
  checked_label: "Cancel",
  unchecked_label: "Select",
  force_random_id: true
```

Должно работать как нужно

*Замечание:* атрибут name становится обязательным. Без него могут начаться косяки с группировками.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  я и беру оригинальный селектор - '.control__check').change ->... Посмотрите мой скрипт. При изменении вообще не заходит в код обработчика события. Дело в том что по умолчанию, чекбоксы могут быть все не активные. Соответственно радио баттон не подходит.

Comment: @StefanHansch, согласен, поторопился. А можно увидеть во что кофе компилируется?

Comment: @StefanHansch радиобаттоны могут быть выключены в начальном состоянии. Отличие лишь в том, что после выбора обратно в это состояние их привести нельзя. Конечно, если этот плагин дополнительно не ограничивает их.

Comment: @anoam Я добавил исходный код html чекбокса.

Comment: @StefanHansch, супер! Только я просил `js`, который получился из представленного `coffee`.

Answer (score -2):

В исходном html чекбокса строка:

```
<label for="labelauty-179303"><span class="labelauty-unchecked-image</span>
```

Несколько не валидна. Ошибка переноса или ошибка генератора html?

Если ошибка была при генерировании написании html, то может и javascript спотыкается на данном моменте?

При изменении html на валидный как минимум срабатывает alert в функции change:

https://jsfiddle.net/nxnpn20j/3/

Единственное, что было изменено - переписан код с события turbolinks:load на $(document).ready

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее, все валидно. Ваш ответ является скорее вопросом. В следующий раз пишите подобные сообщения в комментарии к вопросу.

Comment: @ilyaplot нет, это вы посмотрите внимательнее.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, есть проблемы

Comment: Извиняюсь, не разобрался до конца с тем, как правильно взаимодействовать с ответами/комментариями. В комментарий к вопросу писать мне система не даёт.